# Excel - How to select multiple columns as a range

Tags: c#, excel

I hoped and guessed we could probably have something like this:

```
ws.Range("D").VerticalAlignment
```

Which appeared to be wrong a bit later.

**Edit**:
previously in question I mentioned:

```
ws.Range("A:F").VerticalAlignment
```

And given a feedback which mentioned that was correct.

As you might see, I'm going to select the whole columns of A to F, what could be the right way doing so?

Comment: Exactly how you have done it `Range("A:F", "G:G", "S:Z")`

Comment: oh it cause an error for me

Comment: is this right also: ws.Range("D") ?

Comment: At least one of these caused error for me, so I thought there could be problems on calling these "Named Ranges", if what I mentioned in my comment is wrong tell me to update the question, thanks

Comment: I would recommend against using multiple periods (.) on the same line - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/158752/34092 .

Comment: thanks, will take that as an advice.

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have done is fine, but you haven't passed an argument to `VerticalAlignment`, assuming `ws` is set correctly too.

```
Range("D:D").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
Range("A:F").VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignTop
```

As a few examples.

Answer (score 2):

Hi this confused me a bit when I needed to do it as well. I'll do my best to explain!

You can select single cells (still classed as a Range I believe) using

```
WorkSheet.Cells[row, column]
```

To select multiple Cells you could do something like this

```
Range startCell = excelSheet.Cells[1,1];
Range endCell = excelSheet.Cells[3,3];
Range myCellCollection = excelSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];
```

Hope that helps a bit!

Let me know if you want any more clarification, it may not be the most efficient way but it is still running in my application :)

Answer (score -3):

How about selecting `A1:F1` then use

```
activecell.EntireColumn.select();
```

Comment: Because using `select` is very bad practice and should avoided where possible.

Comment: @TimWilkinson Thank you, will not use it again!